# How to implement Active Record like 'find' method in Sinatra and Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I am building a simple Sinatra app for training purposes.

I am using the Sequel gem and don't want to use Active Record.

My files are:

/models/idea.rb:

```
class Idea
  attr_reader :id, :title, :description

  def initialize(input)
    @id = input[:id]
    @title = input[:title]
    @description = input[:description]
  end

  def save
    Idea.data.insert(title: title, description: description)
  end

  def self.create_table
    database.create_table? :ideas do
      primary_key :id
      String :title, size: 25
      Text :description
    end
  end

  def self.data
    verify_table_exists
    database[:ideas]
  end

  def self.database
    @database ||= Sequel.sqlite('./db/idea_box.sqlite3')
  end

  def self.all
    data.order(Sequel.desc(:id)).collect do |row|
      Idea.new(row)
    end
  end

  def self.verify_table_exists
    @table_exists ||= (create_table || true)
  end

  def self.find(params)
    data.where(id: params)
  end
# I also tried this:
#
#  def self.find(params)
#    data.where(id: params).collect do |row|
#      Idea.new(row)
#    end
#  end

  end
end
```

/views/edit.haml:

```
%h1 Edit idea
%form{action:"/#{@idea.id}", method: "post"}
  %input{type: "hidden", name: "_method", value: "put"}
  %input{type: "text", name: "idea_name", value: "#{@idea.title}"}
  %br
  %textarea{name: "idea_description", value: "#{@idea.description}"}
  %br
  %input{type: "submit", value: "Submit"}
```

application.rb:

```
require './models/idea'


Bundler.require

helpers do
  def title
    if @title
      "#{@tile} -- IdeaBox"
    else
        "IdeaBox"
    end
  end

  def delete_idea_button(idea_id)
    haml :_delete_idea_button, locals: {idea_id: idea_id}
  end
end



get '/' do
  @ideas = Idea.all
  haml :index
end

not_found do
  haml :error
end

post '/create' do


  idea = Idea.new(title: params['idea_name'], description: params['idea_description'])
  idea.save

  redirect to('/')
end

get '/edit/:id' do
  @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Edit form"
  haml :edit
end

put ':id' do
  @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Edit form"
  haml :edit
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the `find` method will work when you use something like this:

```
def self.find(params)
  record = data[id: params]
  if record.nil?
    nil
    # or raise an exception...
  else
    self.new(record)
  end
end
```

But you also have to reimplement some features that Active Record already has, for example some kind of `persisted?` method to check if the record is already present in the database and update the record instead of creating a new one.

With your current implementation of `save` it will create a new record each time you call it. It may also be better if you don't set the `id` yourself but let the `auto_increment` of your database handle that.